# Mapping on whole space inducing a mapping on homologies for a sphere,

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I'm trying to prove that the mapping $r_i\colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, $r_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(x_1,\dots,-x_i,\dots,x_n)$ induces multiplying by (-1) in $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$.

We see that $r_i(S^{n-1})=S^{n-1}$. I wanted to show that n-chain $z\in C_n(S^{n-1})$ is mapped to $-z$, but I don't know how and if it is so (then using a differential would finish the proof).
Of course $r_i$ is a homeomorphism and homotopy equivalence. Hence, $H_{n-1}(r_i)\colon H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})\rightarrow H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$ is a homomorphism, but I don't know how to connect these two mappings.

Any hints?

Edit: but hey! isn't that ok? This reflection maps chain z to z', and then rotation around any other axis by $\pi$ maps it on a $-z$. This is a homotopy equivalence, so doesn't change homology group, and then we can use the differential, which would finish the proof. Is that a good idea? Please, feel free to comment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're familiar with de Rham cohomology, then it's clear that $r$ acts on $H^n_{\text{dR}}(S^n) = H_n(S^n) \otimes \mathbb{R}$ by $\det r$. The induced map $r_*$ is also much easier to work out in cellular, rather than singular, homology.

Comment: I'm familliar only with singular homologies right now. Thanks for the comment, just an another urge to get familiar with de Rham.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea captures some nice intuition but if you want to be formal, then in singular homology the $\pi$-rotation doesn't map it to $"-z"$: formally those are different singular simplices (although homologous).

The simplest way to solve this is to build a simplicial complex model on the sphere and approximate $r$ via a simplicial map that is homotopic to $r$. Then you just follow the definitions.

---

A more abstract way is by induction and Mayer-Vietoris: if $S$ is a neighborhood of the hemisphere $\{j\geq 0\}$ for some $j\neq i$ and $N$ a neighborhood of the opposite hemisphere, $S\cap N$ is an $(n-2)$-sphere up to homotopy equivalence, both $N$ and $S$ are fixed by $r$ and you have the diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})=H_{n-1}(N\cup S)&\simeq & H_{n-2}(S\cap N)\simeq H_{n-2}(S^{n-2})\\
\downarrow_{r} &  & \downarrow_r\\
H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})=H_{n-1}(N\cup S)&\simeq & H_{n-2}(S\cap N)\simeq H_{n-2}(S^{n-2})\\
\end{array}
$$
Of course, the restriction of $r$ to the "equator" $R\cap S$ has the same form and sends a generator to its inverse, so the same is true for $H_{n-1}$. For the $S^0$-shpere, you again can do it directly from the definition.

---

Yet another insight is the following: 
$$H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})\simeq H_{n-1}(R^n\setminus\{0\})\simeq H_n(R^n,R^n\setminus\{0\})$$ by the deformation retraction and long exact sequence: but the homology $H_n(R^n, R^n\setminus\{0\})$ is an "orientation" (see Hatcher, 233ff) which is changed by $r$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for that nice answer! :) I think I got it, also tried to use M-V sequence, but I failed. Yeah, it's a nice and elegant solution. I cannot understand the last remark for the moment, but it's rather lack of my knowledge, gonna think about it tommorow, thanks! And we hadn't got simplicial homologies on the lecture, so I 'have' to use singular ones.